# Query to find all lines connected to other

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, spatial

I have problem with one spatial (Oracle) query.
Simplified overview of the problem is:

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE thin_lines (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  geom SDO_GEOMETRY),
  color VARCHAR2(32);

CREATE TABLE thick_lines (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  geom SDO_GEOMETRY),
  color VARCHAR2(32);
```

Both tables contain 2D lines.
The example picture:

[image]

The problem:

I want to create SQL query or PL/SQL procedure to find ids of all blue thin lines (whole blue branch comprising of blue lines) connected to the thick green lines.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have a look at SDO_RELATE operator: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78531

Comment: Sorry, but I know Oracle Spatial operators. I can find blue lines directly connected to the green lines but the problem is, that there are few other blue lines connected to blue line directly connected to green one. A I need to find all blue lines.

Comment: Show us the query you use to find the blue lines directly connected to the green and we will help you to write a recursive query to locate the other branches

Comment: Query to find blue lines directly connected to green ones: select thin.id from thin_lines thin, thick_lines thick where thin.color='blue' and thick.color='green' and sdo_touch(thin.geom, thick.geom) = 'TRUE';

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Oracle Spatial Data Type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm) and [SDO_INTERSECTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#i857570).

I have not tested this and it likely does not work; but it should be a helpful starting point:

```
DECLARE
    type intersecting_blue_line is table of NUMBER;
    RT_GL thick_lines%ROWTYPE;
    CURSOR get_GreenLines IS
        SELECT *
        FROM thick_lines TKL
        WHERE TKL.color = 'Green';

BEGIN
    OPEN get_GreenLines;
    LOOP
        FETCH get_GreenLines INTO RT_GL;

        for x in (SELECT TNL.id, 
                  FROM thin_lines TNL
                  WHERE TNL.color = 'Blue'
                  AND SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION(RT_GL.geom, TNL.geom, 0.005) IS NOT NULL;)
        LOOP
            intersecting_blue_line := x.id;
        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE get_tables;
END;

SELECT * FROM intersecting_blue_line;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found some solution to do this with one query (Oracle 11.2):

```
WITH recursive (p1, p2) AS (
  SELECT thin.connection_id, thin.geom FROM thin_lines thin, thick_lines thick
    WHERE sdo_touch(thin.geom, thick.geom) = 'TRUE' AND thick.color = 'green' AND thin.color = 'blue'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT thin.connection_id, thin.geom FROM thin_lines thin, recursive r
    WHERE sdo_touch(thin.geom, r.p2) = 'TRUE' and thin.color='blue'
)
CYCLE p1 SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT distinct p1 FROM recursive order by p1;
```

It works, but for small set of thin and thick lines. For huge set it is unusable for me.